# Android Studio Volley Add Parameters to POST Request

Tags: android, android-studio, post, android-volley

I am trying to pass parameters to a POST request by using Volley in an Android Studio Project.
In fact i want to send a nickname through a POST request.
By this way my php file will send me back a json array that i will parse.

I tested my parsing by wrinting hard this nickname in my php file => it worked and i get back a json with the corrects values.
Now i want to send this nickname by adding him in the parameters of my POST request.

I tried to use the GetParams method but it doesnt work.

This is my code

```
private void loadJsonArray() {
    final String pseudo = "test";
    JsonArrayRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, array_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray responseArray) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        StringBuilder textViewData = new StringBuilder();
                        //Parse the JSON response array by iterating over it
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject response = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Integer centreInteretId = response.getInt("Id");
                            String libelle = response.getString("Libelle");
                            Integer IsSelect = response.getInt("IsSelect");

                            //Create String out of the Parsed JSON

                            textViewData.append("CentreInteret Id: ")
                                    .append(centreInteretId.toString()).append(NEW_LINE);
                            textViewData.append("Libelle: ").append(libelle).append(NEW_LINE);
                            textViewData.append("IsSelect: ").append(IsSelect).append(NEW_LINE);

                            //Populate textView with the response
                            mTxtDisplay.setText(textViewData.toString());
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage() + " lol", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," les params", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    map.put("pseudo",pseudo);
                    //map.put("oldPassword",oldPassword);
                    return map;
                }
            };

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
}
```

As you can see in my code im trying to send the value "test" through a POST request

Do you have an idea of where is the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you to check response using log in onResponse() eg. Log.v("response",response.toString()); , it will help to understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

if request need Content-Type in Header you need override headers of your Request 
By This Method :

```
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return params;
    }
```

if don't work pleas tell me to search for another solution .